# Oracle SQL: LEAST() returns multiple rows...?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-functions

A co-worker just came to me with a puzzling SQL query:

(essentially)

```
SELECT LEAST(id) FROM tableA A, tableB B WHERE a.name = b.name(+)
```

The result set returned lists three numbers however:

> LEAST(id)
>   --------------
>   621
>   644
>   689

(all being IDs that meet the query as if it lacked the LEAST function all together)

Why? =)

Comment: I don't know Oracle, and I'm curious about the (+) after b.name. What's this syntax indicate? An outer join?

Comment: the (+) indicates which table in the outer join all of the rows should be imported from

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[LEAST(x,y,...)](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/least.php) is not an aggregate function. It works only on its parameters. The function you want is MIN(x).

For each record, you're running LEAST(id), which will always return id. If you were passing LEAST more parameters, you would see different results. For example, `LEAST(5,6,7) = 5`. LEAST always returns the smallest **of its parameters**, whereas MIN returns the smallest **of every record**.